# does apt-get checks cache directory before downloading packages

Tags: apt, synaptic

I wanted to do offline installation of some packages on an ubuntu machine which is not connected to internet. I have those packages on storage device. Can i use apt-get to install it

does apt-get checks cache directory before  downloading packages?

Comment: Yes it does check it's cache before downloading it again.

Comment: Testing, it does seem to check the cache directory. A full set of answers is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt

Answer (score 2):

If you have the packages (`.deb` files), `apt-get` is not the best tool. Read `man dpkg` and use `dpkg -i` to install the `.deb` files.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd recommend using `dpkg -i`, as [waltinator wrote](https://askubuntu.com/a/932250/480880) and it's the safe and sane method.

However, if you have a vary large number of packages, and you wish to easily manage installing and uninstalling them, with dependency management, the following should work:

```
sudo apt-get -o dir::cache::archives=/path/to/directory/containing/archives/ -o dir::state::lists=/path/to/directory/containing/lists --no-download install your-packages
```

In order for dependency management etc. to work properly, you may need to copy the package metadata (normally present at `/var/lib/apt/lists/`) to `/path/to/directory/containing/lists` on the offline computer.

You could also just copy the packages and the lists directly into the default directories `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, respectively, on the offline computer and skip the options part (`-o dir::cache::archives=/path/to/directory/containing/archives/ -o dir::state::lists=/path/to/directory/containing/lists`).